# How to group values belonging to SHIP_ID on the same row for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried everything but still can't group values that belong to SHIP_ID on the same row.

How can I have all values belonging to the same SHIP_ID on the same row?

For example this is my original table:

| DISTANCE_CODE | SHIP_ID | SHIP_COUNTRY | Unique_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1245_COD |  | 54 |
|  |  | Tunisia | 58 |
| 1C254 |  |  | 60 |
|  | 1100_COD |  | 82 |
|  |  | Oman | 85 |
| E9663 |  |  | 91 |
| J9668 |  |  | 93 |
| R9664 |  |  | 96 |
| S9669 |  |  | 98 |
| T9662 |  |  | 101 |
| 79663 |  |  | 106 |
| E1661 |  |  | 108 |
|  | 1245_CR |  | 110 |
|  |  | Chile | 115 |
| 99Z254 |  |  | 116 |
| 55X33 |  |  | 121 |

Expected results:

| DISTANCE_CODE | SHIP_ID | SHIP_COUNTRY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1C254 | 1245_COD | Tunisia |
| E9663 | 1100_COD | Oman |
| J9668 | 1100_COD | Oman |
| R9664 | 1100_COD | Oman |
| S9669 | 1100_COD | Oman |
| T9662 | 1100_COD | Oman |
| 79663 | 1100_COD | Oman |
| E1661 | 1100_COD | Oman |
| 99Z254 | 1245_CR | Chile |
| 55X33 | 1245_CR | Chile |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Based on the table data you have provided. I don't see any possible way to generate your expected results. There is no information in the original table linking the rows together, every row is unique.

Comment: Are the empty cells NULL or empty strings?

Comment: Empty cells are NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hope that this dataset is being fixed, however here is some code that produces the output you are looking for. I do not know if your examples had the same number of columns as your dataset, but in my example the table in question was called `Table_1`

I assumed that `UNIQUE_KEY` was always increasing.

```
-- Start by obtaining all of the SHIP_IDs
WITH Ships AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table_1 
    WHERE SHIP_ID IS NOT NULL

-- Compute the unique key of the next ship id for this set.
), NextShips AS (
    SELECT 
      Ships.UNIQUE_KEY as ShipKey, 
      MIN(NextShip.UNIQUE_KEY) as NextShipKey 
    FROM Ships
    LEFT JOIN Ships as NextShip ON NextShip.UNIQUE_KEY > Ships.UNIQUE_KEY
    GROUP BY Ships.UNIQUE_KEY

-- Due to the calculation above, the last ship id will always have NULL as the next ship id.
), NullFix AS (
    SELECT 
      ShipKey,
      CASE WHEN NextShipKey IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP 1 UNIQUE_KEY FROM Table_1 ORDER BY UNIQUE_KEY DESC) ELSE NextShipKey END as NextShipKey
    FROM NextShips
)

-- Join the table onto itself, once for each column, being very mindful of which columns come from where.
SELECT 
  DistanceCodes.DISTANCE_CODE
, ShipId.SHIP_ID
, ShipCountries.SHIP_COUNTRY    
FROM NullFix 
JOIN Table_1 AS ShipId ON NullFix.ShipKey = ShipId.UNIQUE_KEY
JOIN Table_1 as DistanceCodes ON DistanceCodes.UNIQUE_KEY >= NullFix.ShipKey AND DistanceCodes.UNIQUE_KEY <= NullFix.NextShipKey AND DistanceCodes.DISTANCE_CODE IS NOT NULL
JOIN Table_1 as ShipCountries ON ShipCountries.UNIQUE_KEY >= NullFix.ShipKey AND ShipCountries.UNIQUE_KEY <= NullFix.NextShipKey AND ShipCountries.SHIP_COUNTRY IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @S.Walker. It really helped me understand

Comment: Working perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Here you have a version with **window function lead**. [Lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) provides access to a subsequent rows in the same result. This capability is available from SQL Server 2012+.

```
with t as
(
  select 
    unique_key,
    ship_id,
    lead(distance_code,2) over(order by unique_key) distance_code,
    lead(ship_country,1) over(order by unique_key) ship_country,
    sum(case when ship_id is null then 0 else 1 end) over(order by unique_key) gr
  from [shipping]
) 
select 
  distance_code,
  max(ship_id) over (partition by gr) ship_id,
  max(ship_country) over (partition by gr) ship_country
from t
where distance_code is not null 
order by unique_key
```

```
-- Result
/**
 * +---------------+----------+---------------+
 * | distance_code | ship_id  | ship_country  |
 * +---------------+----------+---------------+
 * | 1C254         | 1245_COD | Tunisia       |
 * | E9663         | 1100_COD | Oman          |
 * | J9668         | 1100_COD | Oman          |
 * | R9664         | 1100_COD | Oman          |
 * | S9669         | 1100_COD | Oman          |
 * | T9662         | 1100_COD | Oman          |
 * | 79663         | 1100_COD | Oman          |
 * | E1661         | 1100_COD | Oman          |
 * | 99Z254        | 1245_CR  | Chile         |
 * | 55X33         | 1245_CR  | Chile         |
 * +---------------+----------+---------------+
 */
```

**Original answer:**

Here is a possible solution using a stored procedure.

```
create procedure sp_seq
as

create table #shipping (
    [DISTANCE_CODE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SHIP_ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SHIP_COUNTRY] [nvarchar](255) NULL,    
)

declare cur cursor for 

select [DISTANCE_CODE]
      ,[SHIP_ID]
      ,[SHIP_COUNTRY]
  from [dbo].[shipping] order by [Unique_key]

declare @DISTANCE_CODE varchar(255), @SHIP_ID varchar(255), @SHIP_COUNTRY varchar(255)

declare @distance varchar(255), @id varchar(255), @country varchar(255)

open cur
fetch next from cur into @DISTANCE_CODE,@SHIP_ID,@SHIP_COUNTRY

while @@FETCH_STATUS =0 
begin

    if (@SHIP_ID is not null and @SHIP_ID != @id) 
        select @distance=null,@id=null,@country=null

    if (@DISTANCE_CODE is not null) set @distance = @DISTANCE_CODE
    if (@SHIP_ID is not null) set @id = @SHIP_ID
    if (@SHIP_COUNTRY is not null) set @country = @SHIP_COUNTRY 
    
    if (@distance is not null and @id is not null and @country is not null)
        insert into #shipping(DISTANCE_CODE,SHIP_ID,SHIP_COUNTRY) 
        select @distance,@id,@country
            
    fetch next from cur into @DISTANCE_CODE,@SHIP_ID,@SHIP_COUNTRY
end
close cur
deallocate cur

select * from #shipping

go
```

Result:

```
exec sp_seq

/*
DISTANCE_CODE   SHIP_ID     SHIP_COUNTRY
1C254           1245_COD    Tunisia
E9663           1100_COD    Oman
J9668           1100_COD    Oman
R9664           1100_COD    Oman
S9669           1100_COD    Oman
T9662           1100_COD    Oman
79663           1100_COD    Oman
E1661           1100_COD    Oman
99Z254          1245_CR     Chile
55X33           1245_CR     Chile
*/
```

Comment: Working as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would share another solution.

```sql
WITH cte_set AS (
    -- Generate GroupID that increments each time SHIP_ID is populated
    SELECT s.DISTANCE_CODE, s.SHIP_ID, s.SHIP_COUNTRY
        , GroupID = COUNT(s.SHIP_ID) OVER (ORDER BY s.Unique_Key ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM #ship s
), cte_ships AS (
    -- Return table of SHIP_ID+SHIP_COUNTRY to GroupID mappings
    SELECT x.GroupID
        , SHIP_ID = MAX(x.SHIP_ID), SHIP_COUNTRY = MAX(x.SHIP_COUNTRY)
    FROM cte_set x
    GROUP BY x.GroupID
), cte_dc AS (
    -- Return table of DISTANCE_CODE to GroupID mappings
    SELECT x.DISTANCE_CODE, x.GroupID
    FROM cte_set x
    WHERE x.DISTANCE_CODE IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT d.DISTANCE_CODE, s.SHIP_ID, s.SHIP_COUNTRY
FROM cte_dc d
    JOIN cte_ships s ON s.GroupID = d.GroupID;
```

The concept here was that I first generated a unique "GroupID" based on whether the `SHIP_ID` was populated. Each time `SHIP_ID` was populated, the `GroupID` incremented.

Then from that dataset, I generated two new sets...one set contains the `SHIP_ID`, `SHIP_COUNTRY`, `GroupID`. The second set contains the `DISTANCE_CODE`, `GroupID`. And then I joined it all together.

I'd also like to note that it's fairly efficient as well, at least compared to other methods I tried. I ran this against a 2 million record table, and it took 19 seconds to output the results to a temp table.

---

### Sample data

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ship','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ship; --SELECT * FROM #ship
CREATE TABLE #ship (
    DISTANCE_CODE varchar(6) NULL,
    SHIP_ID varchar(8) NULL,
    SHIP_COUNTRY varchar(20) NULL,
    Unique_Key int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
)

INSERT INTO #ship (DISTANCE_CODE, SHIP_ID, SHIP_COUNTRY, Unique_Key)
VALUES (NULL,'1245_COD',NULL,54)
    ,  (NULL,NULL,'Tunisia',58)
    ,  ('1C254',NULL,NULL,60)
    ,  (NULL,'1100_COD',NULL,82)
    ,  (NULL,NULL,'Oman',85)
    ,  ('E9663',NULL,NULL,91)
    ,  ('J9668',NULL,NULL,93)
    ,  ('R9664',NULL,NULL,96)
    ,  ('S9669',NULL,NULL,98)
    ,  ('T9662',NULL,NULL,101)
    ,  ('79663',NULL,NULL,106)
    ,  ('E1661',NULL,NULL,108)
    ,  (NULL,'1245_CR',NULL,110)
    ,  (NULL,NULL,'Chile',115)
    ,  ('99Z254',NULL,NULL,116)
    ,  ('55X33',NULL,NULL,121);
```